# Will brushless controller of Current: 17±1A work on a 13A battery?

Tags: current, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

So I recently bought a
'Motor Brushless Controller for 36V/48V 350W' from Ebay for my e-bike
and then when I contacted the seller about the 'Current' because I didn't know what it meant, and he told me:

"That means the current data is not a fixed value, but fluctuating. It will up to 18A or down to 16A."
*(still waiting for his response)*

This is the item details:

Specification:

- Rated Voltage: 36V/48V
- Rated power: 350 watts
- **Current: 17±1A**

Item on Ebay:
 - http://www.ebay.com/itm/361462855827?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

So I just wanna ask a simple question, will it work on my e-bike?
I have:

- 48V 13A Battery
- 250W Motor Controller (wanted to switch to 350W)
- 250W 8Fun rear wheel hub motor

Comment: much better than your last question from today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

17A+/-1 is not valid without conditions.

This may refer to the surge current for starting a motor which can take 5~8x the Watt/Volt ratio but it affect internal temp rise affect by initial conditions and ambient T.

Batteries are rated in storage time in Amp-hours [Ah] and Cranking Amps CA so 13A must be Ah....

Hopefully it represents a current limited switch sensed and controlled by PWM. with a threshold tolerance (if true)  17A compared to your motor 250w/50V =5A is roughly  17/5A= 3.6x rated load should give good acceleration.

15Ah implies you can go full load 5A for 3h with no acceleration or less with accel.

FWIW, Ebay specs are almost non-existent  and not worthy of trust, but it may be ok for you. Ask for an e-file of user manual.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I think it answered most of what I needed to know :)

Also why would I need an e-file of user manual?